# WinRT write to home group

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone

Is it possible to create new folder in main Windows Phone folder? I am trying to access home group as follows:

```
 var picturesLibrary = KnownFolders.HomeGroup;
 var savedPicturesFolder = await picturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("folderName", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

but it ends up having error. If i specify subfolder like Pictures it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the msdn docs

If your app is a Windows Phone Store app, reading the value of this property raises an exception of type System.Exception.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.storage.knownfolders.homegroup?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

May be it does not supported in windows phone.
[requirment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.storage.knownfolders.homegroup?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> To access the HomeGroup folder, in the app manifest, specify at least
>   one of the following capabilities: Pictures Library, Music Library, or
>   Videos Library. Learn more about these capabilities in 
>    [Access to user resources using the Windows Runtime.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh464936)